# 2 opt swap algorithm complexity

Tags: python, greedy

```
def two_opt(route):
 best = route
 improved = True
 while improved:
      improved = False
      for i in range(1, len(route)-2):
           for j in range(i+1, len(route)):
                if j-i == 1: continue # changes nothing, skip then
                new_route = route[:]
                new_route[i:j] = route[j-1:i-1:-1] # this is the 2woptSwap
                if cost(new_route) < cost(best):
                     best = new_route
                     improved = True
      route = best
 return best
```

What is the time complexity of this algorithm? This is the 2 opt swap algorithm

Answer (score 0):

From how I interpreted it, it would be nested for-loops that compares all edges O(N^2), and every time an improvement is found, do it. O(N). For a total of O(N^3).